# Codeigniter Form Validation not Setting Rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have been stuck for a while trying to setup my validation rules, on my controller I have this:

```
public function login () {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
            'field'=>'username',
            'label'=>'Username',
            'rules'=>'required'
            ));
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->json(array(
                'status'=>'error',
                'errors'=>$this->form_validation->error_array(),
                'test'=>$this->form_validation->get_options()
                ));
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->MUser->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->input->post('username')));
        if(!$user) {
            $this->json(array(
                'status'=>'error',
                'errors'=>array('username'=>'Username is not yet registered.')
                ));
            return;
        } 

        $encpass = sha1($user->salt.$this->input->post('password'));

        if ($encpass != $user->password) {
            $this->json(array(
                'status'=>'error',
                'errors'=>array('password'=>'Invalid username/password, please try again.')
                ));
            return; 
        }

        $this->json(array(
            'status'=>'success',
            'errors'=>''
            ));
    }
```

I also have an extended base controller class and an extended form validation class which are as follows:

```
class AM_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function render_template($view, $data = array(), $internal = false) {
        $view_contents = $this->load->view($view, $data, true);

        $header = $internal?$this->load->view('internal/header',$data,true):$this->load->view('external/header',$data,true);
        $footer = $internal?$this->load->view('internal/footer',$data,true):$this->load->view('external/footer',$data,true);

        $this->output->set_status_header(200,'ok');

        $this->load->view('general/template',array_merge(array(
            'header'=>$header,
            'footer'=>$footer,
            'content'=>$view_contents
            ),$data));
    }

    public function json($data) {
        $this->output->set_status_header(200,'ok')
                    ->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
}

class AM_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    public function __construct($options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }   

    public function correct_captcha ($str) {
        $this->set_message('correct_captcha','Invalid %s answer.');
        return $this->CI->session->userdata('captcha_answer') == $str;
    }

    public function get_options () {
        return $this->_field_data;
    }
}
```

But the problem is every time I try to test the form validation, it always returns false regardless if I have entered some value or not. Any idea what is causing this bug?

By the way, I also tried using CI_Controller only for my controller class, but still no luck

Comment: Is `AM_Controller ` the same class that `index()` is in? if not, what is `index()` in and how is it called? It's very hard to see how the code you show fits together.

Comment: If you are using a lot of AJAX in codeigniter you will be interested in this [AJAX library](https://github.com/joshcam/Codeigniter-jQuery-Ajax). Works well with CI.

Comment: @DFriend yes all controllers are using AM_Controller

Comment: `login()` is handling an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the difference on AJAX request or not

Comment: I don't see that you return any data to the browser from `login()`. Mayabe that happens in your call to `$this->json()` but since you don't show that code it's hard to know what's going on there. Likewise, it's also unknown what is being posted to `login()`. Last, but maybe most important the parameter to`set_rules` is an array of rule arrays so it should look like this  '$this->form_validation->set_rules(array(array('field'=>'username', 'label'=>'Username', 'rules'=>'required')));`

Comment: this->json is defined in the post above in AM_Controller class please read. I already tried that format of set_rules, I also tried set_rules with array of group of rules, and tried to use config file. but still no luck

Comment: I see `this->json` set, but do not see it defined anywhere. Certainly not in the `AM_Controller` class.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, upon hours of testing seems like my POST data was not reaching my server. The fail safe of my htaccess made it look like the rewrite was actually working but it wasn't, it was like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /appmon/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /appmon/index.php
</IfModule>
```

After trying things without htaccess things worked, properly. Thanks to everyone